# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc returned wrong DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, utc

I called method:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time"))  // UTC+0
```

It is returned DateTime for one hour larger than the correct DateTime. 
Why? How will it fix?

Returned value should be equal DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()

Comment: You might want to check out https://nodatime.org/ if you have to convert lots of dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTC is equal to GMT. But currently we're in BST due to summer, which is GMT + 1. `GMT Standard Time` automatically adjusts for daylight savings. Use `Greenwich Standard Time`, rather than `GMT Standard Time` if you don't want to adjust for daylight savings.

EDIT: All you have to do is change `GMT Standard Time` to `Greenwich Standard Time` (See below)

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Greenwich Standard Time"))
```

Comment: How to me will convert with GMT? Please will give example code.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` already retuns UTC, you do not need to convert that *again* to UTC.

Hint: Use `DateTime.UtcNow` if you really just need UTC, then you don't have to care about time zones at all and what your local time zone may be.

Update: Oh, and "GMT standard Time" is not "Greenwich mean time".

Comment: This code run into a method. Time zone is parametor of the method.